# Multiple clients on server with multithreading using Socket Programming in C

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, connection, serversocket

I want to write some code using multithreading and sockets to create a server and this server can accept four connections (clients)

How can I receive and send data to the client? How do I know from which client I receive my data?

This the code:

```
if (listen(serverSocket, 20) == 0)
        printf("Listening\n");
    else
        printf("Error\n");

    int i = 0;
    while (1){
        addr_size = sizeof(serverStorage);

        //accept
        newSocket = accept(serverSocket,
                           (struct sockaddr*)&serverStorage,
                           &addr_size);
       
        int type = 0;
        recv(newSocket,
             &type, sizeof(type), 0);
        if (type == 1) {
            // Creater readers thread
            if (pthread_create(&readerthreads[i++], NULL,
                               reader, &newSocket)
                != 0)

                // Error in creating thread
                printf("Failed to create thread\n");
        }
        else if (type == 2) {
            // Create writers thread
            if (pthread_create(&writerthreads[i++], NULL,
                               writer, &newSocket)
                != 0)

                // Error in creating thread
                printf("Failed to create thread\n");
        }

        if (i >= 5) {
            // Update i
            i = 0;

            while (i < 5) {
                // Suspend execution of
                // the calling thread
                // until the target
                // thread terminates
                pthread_join(writerthreads[i++],
                             NULL);
                pthread_join(readerthreads[i++],
                             NULL);
            }

            // Update i
            i = 0;
        }
    }
```

How can I modify it to receive data from a specific client and send also to specific client?

there is the method `send();` and `recv();` but I don't know How the variable NewSocket tell to which client is sending it

Comment: Where `newSocket` is declared? It is shared between threads. Store each `newSocket` value for each thread individually.

Comment: it's decleared at the beginning of main 
Thank you I will store the values